# RewriteRule doesn't match a certain URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\/]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]*)/?(company|person)/?$  $1/$2/index\.php\?misc=$3&$4
```

This doesn't match `http://example.com/zufang/zjqj_2-/person/`.

What RewriteRule can I use to match both  `example.com/zufang/zjqj_2-/person/` and `xxx.com/zufang/person/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule appears to be trying to match the `example.com` part. The domain is not matched in a RewriteRule, however. Also, since the entire second section is optional note that you may have a problem with your resulting `misc=$3&$4` since that would be `misc=&person` when the second section isn't present. Here's an updated rule with some other minor cleanup:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]*)?/?(company|person)/?$  /$1/index.php?misc=$2&$3
```

One additional item I'm not 100% sure about, I don't think characters have to be escaped within character match blocks. If that's the case, the following would be slightly cleaner:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z0-9-_]*)?/?(company|person)/?$  /$1/index.php?misc=$2&$3
```

Comment: With a regular match  http://xxx.com/zufang/zjqj_2-/person/  and http://xxx.com/zufang/person/